# Bingo Game, class interface errors?

Tags: class, interface, enums, undeclared-identifier

**Can anyone tell me why I am getting these errors? And if so, how do i fix them?**

```
Bingo.java:176: ']' expected
private static void makeCard(int[][] card, int[picks])
                                               ^
Bingo.java:176: ')' expected
private static void makeCard(int[][] card, int[picks])
                                                    ^
Bingo.java:176: illegal start of type
private static void makeCard(int[][] card, int[picks])
                                                     ^
Bingo.java:176: <identifier> expected
private static void makeCard(int[][] card, int[picks])
                                                      ^
Bingo.java:177: ';' expected
{
 ^
Bingo.java:178: illegal start of type
    System.out.println("Current Number Picks: \n");
          ^
Bingo.java:178: ';' expected
    System.out.println("Current Number Picks: \n");
              ^
Bingo.java:178: invalid method declaration; return type required
    System.out.println("Current Number Picks: \n");
               ^
Bingo.java:178: illegal start of type
    System.out.println("Current Number Picks: \n");
                       ^
Bingo.java:181: illegal start of type
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
            ^
Bingo.java:181: ')' expected
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
                      ^
Bingo.java:181: illegal start of type
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
                       ^
Bingo.java:181: <identifier> expected
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
                        ^
Bingo.java:181: ';' expected
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
                         ^
Bingo.java:181: > expected
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
                                 ^
Bingo.java:181: '(' expected
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
                                    ^
Bingo.java:189: class, interface, or enum expected
private static void announceWin(int winFound, int numPicks)
               ^
Bingo.java:192: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
Bingo.java:196: class, interface, or enum expected
    for (int i = 0;  i < numPicks;  i++){
                     ^
Bingo.java:196: class, interface, or enum expected
    for (int i = 0;  i < numPicks;  i++){
                                    ^
Bingo.java:198: class, interface, or enum expected
                            return true;}
                                        ^
Bingo.java:202: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
22 errors
```

**Here is the code:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Bingo
{
public static final int ROWS = 5;
public static final int COLS = 5;
public static final int VERTICAL = 1;
public static final int DIAGONAL = 2;
public static final int HORIZONTAL = 3;
public static int winFound;
public static int currPick = 0;
public static int randomPick;
public static int WinFound;

public static void main(String[] args)
{   
int Totcards;
int[][] card = new int[ROWS][COLS];

fillCard (card);
printCard(card);
playGame(card);
printCard(card);

  }

private static void fillCard (int[][] card)
{
//  FileReader fileIn = new FileReader("Bingo.in");
//  Bufferreader in = new Bufferreader(fileIn);

    try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("bingo.in"));
      for (int i=0; i<card.length; i++){
               for (int j=0; j<card[0].length; j++){
                card[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
      System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());
    }

}

private static void printCard (int[][] card)
{
    System.out.println("\n\tYOUR BINGO CARD : ");
    System.out.println("\n\tB    I    N    G    O");
    System.out.println("\t----------------------");

    for (int i=0; i<card.length; i++){
          for (int j=0; j<card[0].length; j++){
              System.out.print("\t" + card[i][j]);
              }
    System.out.print("\n");
    }
}

private static void playGame (int[][] card)
{

    int numPicks = 0;       

    while (true)
            {
               markCard (card);   // Generate a random num & zero-it out
       winFound = checkForWin(card);  //  Look for zero sums
       numPicks++;

               if (winFound != 0)
               {
                 announceWin (winFound, numPicks);
                 return;
               }
            }


  }     
private static void markCard (int[][] card)
{
  int randomPick = (int) (Math.random() * 74) + 1;

      for (int j = 0;  j < ROWS;  j++){
        for (int k = 0;  k < COLS;  k++){
            if (card[j][k]==randomPick)
                    card[j][k] = 0;}
    System.out.print(" " + randomPick);
    }
}

private static int checkForWin(int[][] card)
{
  int sum=0;

   for (int i = 0;  i < ROWS;  i++)
       {
        sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0;  j < COLS;  j++)
        sum += card[i][j];

        if (sum == 0)
            return HORIZONTAL;
       }

       for (int j = 0;  j < COLS;  j++)
       {
         sum = 0;
         for (int i = 0;  i < ROWS;  i++)
            sum += card[i][j];

        if (sum == 0)
            return VERTICAL;
       }

       sum = 0;
       for (int i = 0;  i < ROWS;  i++)
            sum += card[i][ROWS-i-1];
       if (sum == 0)
            return DIAGONAL;

       sum = 0;
       for (int i = 0;  i < ROWS;  i++)
          sum += card[i][i];

       if (sum == 0)
            return DIAGONAL;

       return WinFound;
    } 

private static void makeCard(int[][] card, int[picks])
{
    System.out.println("Current Number Picks: \n");
            int count = 100;
            int currPick = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
             currPick = (int)(Math.random() * 74) + 1;
             System.out.print(" " + currPick + "\n");
    picks[i] = currPick;
            System.out.print("i: " + i);
            }
}

private static void announceWin(int winFound, int numPicks)
{
System.out.println("winFound: " + winFound + "numpicks: " + numPicks);
}

private static boolean duplicate (int currPick, int[picks], int numPicks)
{
    for (int i = 0;  i < numPicks;  i++){
                    if (picks[i] == currPick){
                            return true;}
        }
            return false;

}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accepting an int array parameter incorrectly.

You have int [picks] where it should be int[] picks

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Bingo
{
public static final int ROWS = 5;
public static final int COLS = 5;
public static final int VERTICAL = 1;
public static final int DIAGONAL = 2;
public static final int HORIZONTAL = 3;
public static int winFound;
public static int currPick = 0;
public static int randomPick;
public static int WinFound;

public static void main(String[] args)
{   
int Totcards;
int[][] card = new int[ROWS][COLS];

fillCard (card);
printCard(card);
playGame(card);
printCard(card);

  }

private static void fillCard (int[][] card)
{
//  FileReader fileIn = new FileReader("Bingo.in");
//  Bufferreader in = new Bufferreader(fileIn);

    try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("bingo.in"));
      for (int i=0; i<card.length; i++){
               for (int j=0; j<card[0].length; j++){
                card[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
      System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());
    }

}

private static void printCard (int[][] card)
{
    System.out.println("\n\tYOUR BINGO CARD : ");
    System.out.println("\n\tB    I    N    G    O");
    System.out.println("\t----------------------");

    for (int i=0; i<card.length; i++){
          for (int j=0; j<card[0].length; j++){
              System.out.print("\t" + card[i][j]);
              }
    System.out.print("\n");
    }
}

private static void playGame (int[][] card)
{

    int numPicks = 0;       

    while (true)
            {
               markCard (card);   // Generate a random num & zero-it out
       winFound = checkForWin(card);  //  Look for zero sums
       numPicks++;

               if (winFound != 0)
               {
                 announceWin (winFound, numPicks);
                 return;
               }
            }


  }     
private static void markCard (int[][] card)
{
  int randomPick = (int) (Math.random() * 74) + 1;

      for (int j = 0;  j < ROWS;  j++){
        for (int k = 0;  k < COLS;  k++){
            if (card[j][k]==randomPick)
                    card[j][k] = 0;}
    System.out.print(" " + randomPick);
    }
}

private static int checkForWin(int[][] card)
{
  int sum=0;

   for (int i = 0;  i < ROWS;  i++)
       {
        sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0;  j < COLS;  j++)
        sum += card[i][j];

        if (sum == 0)
            return HORIZONTAL;
       }

       for (int j = 0;  j < COLS;  j++)
       {
         sum = 0;
         for (int i = 0;  i < ROWS;  i++)
            sum += card[i][j];

        if (sum == 0)
            return VERTICAL;
       }

       sum = 0;
       for (int i = 0;  i < ROWS;  i++)
            sum += card[i][ROWS-i-1];
       if (sum == 0)
            return DIAGONAL;

       sum = 0;
       for (int i = 0;  i < ROWS;  i++)
          sum += card[i][i];

       if (sum == 0)
            return DIAGONAL;

       return WinFound;
    } 

private static void makeCard(int[][] card, int[] picks)
{
    System.out.println("Current Number Picks: \n");
            int count = 100;
            int currPick = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
             currPick = (int)(Math.random() * 74) + 1;
             System.out.print(" " + currPick + "\n");
    picks[i] = currPick;
            System.out.print("i: " + i);
            }
}

private static void announceWin(int winFound, int numPicks)
{
    System.out.println("winFound: " + winFound + "numpicks: " + numPicks);
}

private static boolean duplicate (int currPick, int[] picks, int numPicks)
{
    for (int i = 0;  i < numPicks;  i++){
                    if (picks[i] == currPick){
                            return true;}
        }
            return false;

}
}
```

Compiles for me